# Could not load dynamic library .\RenderSystem_GL_d. System Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c++, ogre

I am using OGRE 1.8.1 SDK for Visual C++ 2010 (32-bit) from ogre3d.org/download/sdk and Ogre_VC10_Express_AppWizard_1.8.0.exe downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/ogreaddons/ogreappwizards/downloads. After a successful build when i am runnin application i am getting following error:

OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library .\RenderSystem_GL_d.  System Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

in DynLib::load at ........\OgreMain\src\OgreDynLib.cpp (line 93)

Seems to me that there is a mismatch of some 32bit/64bit dlls but reinstalling directx didn't solved the problem.
I am new to OGRE, kindly guide me on this and i am using windows 8(64bit) and Microsoft visual C++ 2010 Express.

Edit: I tried installing SDK and directly run SampleBrowser (Without using AppWizard) but same error occurred again(build was successful).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the 64-bit version of Ogre. I guess this is cause by different ABI of your application build with a 64-bit compiler and a 32-bit dll coming from the SDK which you installed.
So when the lib-loader tries to load the rendersystem dll this will fail and you get the error.

When no 64-version is available try to compile Ogre on your own with your 64-bit compiler.